# Calculation of path integral in QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral

I am studing QFT using the text book of Srednicki's. And I am stuck on one of calculations of the integrals in his book.

Consider a harmonic oscillator with hamiltonian:
[image]

We can write the following integral for the transition from ground state to ground state:
[image]

In his book, he said: Passing to the lagrangian formulation then gives:
[image]

What does he mean by passing to the lagrangian formulation? And how did he calculate the $Dp$ part?

It's on page 46 of the book:
http://chaosbook.org/FieldTheory/extras/SrednickiQFT03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Going from the Hamiltonian to the Lagrangian formulation usually means integrating out the momentum variables. In this case the momentum integrations in the phase space [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is just [Gaussian integrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason he left out the $hp$ term in the second  equation you quoted. If you put it back as it is in the earlier sections, and then do the $p$ inetegrals you get the $(m/2)(\dot q+h)^2$  term directly.